# How do I calculate the field from a polarised dielectric if there is also a boundary condition?

Tags: electrostatics, dielectric

If we have a polarised dielectric in a vacuum, we can calculate the resulting scalar potential field at a position $\textbf{r}$
$$\phi(\textbf{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}}\int_{\alpha}\frac{\textbf{P}(\textbf{R})\cdot(\textbf{R}-\textbf{r})}{|\textbf{R}-\textbf{r}|^{3}}d\beta$$
where $\textbf{R}$ is the coordinate of infinitesimal volume element $d\beta$,$\alpha$ represents the region of the dielectric and $\textbf{P}(\textbf{R})$ is the polarisation density function. This scenario is illustrated here.

[image]

I am interested in finding out what happens if we add an electrode into the region held at some potential, $V$, as illustrated below.

[image]

Assuming that the electrode doesn't induce any further polarisation in the dielectric, how can I now find the potential $\phi(\textbf{r})$ for some position $\textbf{r}$? Do I need to
now solve Laplace's equation using the electrode surface and the dielectric surface as boundary conditions, or can I evaluate it in an easier way? Lastly, how does this change if the electrode is grounded (i.e $0V$ rather than at $V$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have fixed the polarization distribution $\mathbf {P(r)}$ and thus along with it the background field $\phi(\mathbf r)$, its interaction with the metal is not as a "dielectric" anymore, in other words, there be no boundary condition on $\partial \alpha$ associated with it. Instead what you have is a given background field $\phi(\mathbf r)$, or $\mathbf E = -\nabla \phi(\mathbf r)$, such that $\lim_{|\mathbf r|\to \infty} \phi =0$, and in that given field you place a conductor at a given potential.

Denote the induced potential field by $\psi$, $\nabla^2 \psi = 0$, and you must satisfy the boundary conditions on the surface, say, $\mathcal S$, of the conductor as $\psi (\mathcal S) = V$ and at infinity $\lim_{|\mathbf r|\to \infty} (\psi(\mathbf r) - \phi(\mathbf r) )=0$. Nasty.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you know of any example calculations for similar scenarios? I feel like this would help me wrap my head around it a bit better

Comment: If  the electrode is an ellipsoid and if the external field is uniform then the problem is analytically solvable. See Stratton ELECTROMAGNETIC THEORY, chapter 3. and Brownstein: Unique shape of uniformly polarizable dielectrics. I vaguely recall, from the very old days, that instead of directly attacking the problem as a partial DE, it is easier to set up an integral equation for the surface charge, but my recollection is quite vague... maybe you can find this in Feschbach & Morse

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: Not the same problem but this https://doi.org/10.1006/jcph.1993.1073 and this https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.05925.pdf, and the references therein may also help how to set up the integral equation.

Comment: amazing, thanks